# How to check value of defined symbols (Eclipse->Paths & Symbols) in a makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, eclipse-cdt, symbols

We have a project that used to be an Eclipse-managed CDT project. However, I am trying to change it to a standard makefile project.

One of them has a couple of symbols defined in

```
Project Properties->C/C++ General->Paths & Symbols->Symbols.
```

The makefiles generated by Eclipse used to automatically get the value when it was managed. The symbols need to be sent to the compiler. How do I get the value in my own makefile? Is there a way?

Thanks, and sorry, I know the questions sounds convoluted.

Edit:

By symbols I mean the -D symbols for the compiler. What we have is a **COMPILE_FOR_A** & **COMPILE_FOR_B** and the values are either 1 or 0. If **COMPILE_FOR_A**=1, it will use particular values, and if **COMPILE_FOR_B**=1 it will use some other values.

Comment: What symbols are you talking about? Debugging? The -D values for compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [environment variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment) and [conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals) to tell your options to make. Something like:

```
DEFINES = -DFOO

ifeq ($(COMPILE_FOR_A),1)
    DEFINES += -DBAR
else
    DEFINES += -DBAZ
endif
```

Then invoke `make` with/without the variable in the environment:

```
~$ COMPILE_FOR_A=1 make
```